# Delete divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jinja2

So i've got this :

```
<script>
    {% block js %}
    $('#add_file').on('click', function(){
    html = '<div class="row">';
        html += '<div class="col s6 input-field">';
                html += '<input placeholder="Komentaras" name="file_description" type="text" />';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="col s2 top_20">';
                html += '<a class="btn-floating red tooltipped delete"  data-position="top" data-delay="20" data-tooltip="Trinti"><i class="material-icons" id="delete_files">delete</i></a>';
        html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#files').append(html);
});

    {% endblock %}
</script>
```

This block of code generates and adds extra divs depending on the click, the question is, how to delete every generated html one by one, by pressing that generated red btn?

Comment: Add click event to delete button after appending to #files then on the callback function find the parent parent div with class=row and remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
})
```

Note: do not use the same id `id="delete_files"` on the icon

Answer (score 2):

Because it's dynamically added, you can't just use normal jQuery to target it. jQuery works with the DOM that's loaded - not anything after.

So you'd write a function that does:

```
$('#files').on('click', '.delete', function()
{
    $(this).parents().eq(1).remove()   
})
```

refs:

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

https://api.jquery.com/remove/